# Why does tf.Print() not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have this code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

    # batch x time x events x dim
batch = 2
time = 3
events = 4
tensor = np.random.rand(batch, time, events)

tensor[0][0][2] = 0
tensor[0][0][3] = 0

tensor[0][1][3] = 0

tensor[0][2][1] = 0
tensor[0][2][2] = 0
tensor[0][2][3] = 0

tensor[1][0][3] = 0

def cum_sum(prev, cur):
    non_zeros = tf.equal(cur, 0.)
    tf.Print(non_zeros, [non_zeros], "message ")
    tf.Print(cur, [cur])
    return cur

elems = tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)
#alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x, 2*x, -x), elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64))
cum_sum_ = tf.scan(cum_sum, tensor)

s = tf.Session()

s.run(cum_sum_)
```

I have two `tf.Print` statements in the function that I pass to the `tf.scan`, but when I run the cumulative sum, I do not get any print statements. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tf.Print does not work like that. Print nodes need to be into the graph in order to exectue. I highly recommend you to check out [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tf-print-in-tensorflow-aa26e1cff11e) tutorial to learn how to use it.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: according to that tutorial this should work:

```def cum_sum(prev, cur):
    non_zeros = ~tf.equal(cur, 0.)
    tf.Print(non_zeros, [non_zeros], "message ")
    cur_ = tf.Print(cur, [cur])
    return cur_```, but it does not. So I must be doing something wrong again

Comment: oh it does work. But it goes into the stderr of my Jupyter notebook. Thanks

Comment: Does it work for Tensor flow 2.0.? What is the alternative syntax there?

Answer (score 2):

Although, @Ignacio Peletier answer is a fully helpful one it depends on an external site. I find it peculiar that noone mentioned that here. Anyway, for sticking with the rules I provide the answer also here (without having to visit the external link that is) with some extra information:

For `tf.Print` to actually print something it should belong to the graph. To do so, you simply reuse the returned Tensor from the `tf.Print` and pass it to the next op. *Passing it* over to the next op is crucial for actually displaying the message.

So, to use your example it could be rewritten:

```
def cum_sum(prev, cur):
    non_zeros = tf.equal(cur, 0.)
    non_zeros = tf.Print(non_zeros, [non_zeros], "message ")
    cur = tf.Print(cur, [cur])
    return cur
```

which will print `cur` but not `non_zeros` since this node is dangling. Also, I am not sure I can rewrite your code so that `non_zeros` is displayed since it is not actually used in your code after the point you define them (so tensorflow will simply ignore it in non-eager mode).

In general for (a non dangling) node, let's name it `result` somewhere in your code:

```
result = tf.some_op_here()
# the following is actually displaying the contents of result
result = tf.Print(result, [result], 'some arbitrary message here to be displayed before the actual message')
tf.another_op_here_using_result(result)
```

will print the (possibly concatenated) contents of `result`. For a control over the amount of information shown you can also use the parameter `summarize=x` where `x` is the number of parameters being displayed.